# Let $G$ be a group. Prove that $G'$ is central iff ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, derived-subgroup

This is **Exercise 4.11** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach."* According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Inner+automorphisms+is+abelian+iff+derived+subgroup+is+central) and [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Inner%20automorphisms%20abelian%20iff%20derived%20subgroup%20is%20central&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

On page 33 of Roman's book,

> **Definition:** A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is *central* if $H$ is contained in the centre of $G$.

On page 120 *ibid.*, we have

> **Theorem 4.13 (1):** [. . .] $${\rm Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G).$$

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be a group. Prove that $G'$ is central if and only if ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is abelian.

### Thoughts:

I think **Theorem 4.13 (1)** is important here. However, I find it hard to articulate why.

---

Suppose $G'\subseteq Z(G)$. Consider $\gamma_g, \gamma_h\in{\rm Inn}(G)$ for $g, h\in G$. We have for any $x\in G$ that

$$\begin{align}
(\gamma_g\circ\gamma_h)(x)&=\gamma_g(\gamma_h(x))\\
&=\gamma_g(hxh^{-1})\\
&=ghxh^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&=(gh)x(gh)^{-1}\\
&=\gamma_{gh}(x).
\end{align}$$

Now, I just follow my nose. Something tells me I'm heading in the right direction.

Consider $\gamma_{gh}(x)x^{-1}$; that is, $[gh, x]$. This commutes with all elements of $G$ by assumption.

Where do I go from here?

Please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simpler. Since $\mathrm{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)$, then $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ is abelian if and only if $G'\subseteq Z(G)$: recall that for a group $G$, a normal subgroup $N$ contains $G'$ if and only if $G/N$ is abelian.